# how to connect Apache Solr with Cassandra without DSE?

Tags: javascript, node.js, solr, cassandra

I am starting a new project where I have to use **Cassandra** as DBMS, **Apache Solr** as the search engine and **Node.js** as the server scripting language.

I am good with node.js but totally new to Cassandra and Solr.

**what I have now**

- Cassandra server running with some data inside a keyspace `test`.
- Solr server running on port `8983`.

**what am I looking for**

- How to index the data of `test keyspace` from cassandra and make it search-able in Solr.

**note:** We don't have the budget to purchase a DSE licence.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Well, the easiest way to go about it would be to purchase a license for DSE from DataStax.  It delivers with integrated Solr and Cassandra.

Comment: thanks for your comment .. but we don't have the budget to purchase the DSE licence .. we have to go with open source solutions .. I will update the question to mention that

Comment: So what have you tried? [There's](https://github.com/tjake/Solandra) a [multitude](http://bigdatatutor.blogspot.no/2014/08/solr-cassandra-integaration-without.html) of different solutions, or you can write your own using a Cassandra client and SolrJ.

Comment: thanks @MatsLindh .. I checked Solandra before but it seemed like it is an abandoned project now .. so I was afraid of using it .. I will try using SolrJ and I hope that I will find the necessary support on the Internet .. thanks a lot for your comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. As mentioned in some of the comments, you could write your own service using the Cassandra client and the Solr client to read the data from C* and add it to the index.
   The main challenge will be to keep the index up to date.
2. If you don't necessary need to use Solr, but still want to create a Lucene based index, you then could consider the open source [Stratio Cassandra Lucene index](https://github.com/Stratio/cassandra-lucene-index) which uses the Cassandra indexing functionality, but uses Lucene for the actual index and searching.

Good luck!

/Teo

Comment: Thanks for your response. In this project I have to use Solr with Cassandra. So reading data from cassandra and adding it to solr is the unique solution ? Any advice on syncing data between the two ?

Comment: Ok, I see. The only other way I know about is Solandra, but as you already mention, that is an abandoned project. You would then have to make something yourself I guess. There are node / javascript clients for both cassandra and Solr.
In order to keep the two in sync you could use Cassandra [triggers](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlCreateTrigger.html) (although I'm not sure how well they work and how reliable they are) or just make your small service poll Cassandra for changes in some way.